# reading exif title results in chinese signs

Tags: php, exif

I am trying to display some exif-information within an image fallery. the title and subject where set using the windows file properties.

all self defined text is being displayed as a bunch of questionmarks. now, i have set exif.encode_unicode to utf-8 and the text is displayed like a bunch of chinese characters.

the document is set to utf-8, too.

how can I display the correct exif information? or, it may be a problem of how I edit the information? if this is the case, what am i supposed to do??

**edit:** i found a solution by using the programs ExifEraser and MetaEditor. Now using $exif["DocumentName"] and $exif["ImageDescription"]...